# Show Month, Year in Dropdown for current year in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

How to show Month, Year in Dropdown for current year in SSRS 2008

like

```
Jan 2017
Feb 2017
Mar 2017
....
Dec 2017
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These are defined in the Available Values tab of the parameter properties. One option is to manually add hard coded values there. If you want them to be dynamic, you'll need to write a SQL query to generate these values. Then you can add that query to the report as a new dataset and use the query to populate the Available Values.

If you still need help writing the SQL after running a search for it please post a new question with details of what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Hello Steven, yes, i m looking for dynamic date part, appriciate if that SQL part is available.

Comment: As I said, examples are available if you search for it. We're here to answer questions, not work for you. You need to at least try to write it yourself first if you want to learn how to do it.